# cmake MATCHES not working like I think it should

Tags: cmake

In my parent CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(PROGRAMS "CCHIF;CCWIF;FXTINT;FXTCLI")
```

In my child CMakeLists.txt:

```
set (PROJ_LIST "CCHIF;FXTCLI")
MESSAGE(STATUS "Programs is ${PROGRAMS}")
foreach (PROJ ${PROJ_LIST})
if (";${PROJ};" MATCHES ";${PROGRAMS};")
    project(${PROJ})
    add_executable(${PROJ} ${PROJ}.c)
    target_link_libraries(${PROJ} LINK_PUBLIC pthread dl)
    install(TARGETS ${PROJ} DESTINATION ${BIN_DIR})
endif()
    Message ( STATUS "${PROJ} is NOT in the programs list!!!  **********")
endforeach()
```

Output from cmake ..

```
-- Programs is CCHIF;CCWIF;FXTINT;FXTCLI
-- CCHIF is NOT in the programs list!!!  **********
-- FXTCLI is NOT in the programs list!!!  **********
```

I have tried with and without the ";....;" (quote/semicolon)  for the arguments to MATCHES.   I have used MATCHES successfully before.  It isn't working in this case.
I have over 50 sub programs that I am building for many sites.  Some sites need all 50 , some only need a portion of them.  so I would like to put the programs needed in the Parent's CMakeLists.txt for each site. Thanks

Comment: And you are printing the message     `Message ( STATUS "${PROJ} is NOT in the programs list!!!  **********")` in any case, even if it matches because it's out of the if block. To see whether it matches you should add and else block to the if and put the `message()` inside the else block.

Comment: String `CCHIF` doesn't match regular expression `CCHIF;CCWIF;FXTINT;FXTCLI`. However, the opposite is true: srting `CCHIF;CCWIF;FXTINT;FXTCLI` matches regular expression `CCHIF`.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use the subcommand [`list(FIND)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/list.html) to do the same task:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)  # put your version...
set(PROGRAMS CCHIF CCWIF FXTINT FXTCLI)
set(PROJ_LIST CCHIF FXTCLI JACK)  # added JACK to see that it will not match any element in the list
foreach(PROJ ${PROJ_LIST})
    list (FIND PROGRAMS ${PROJ} _index)
    if(${_index} GREATER -1)
        message("Project selected: ${PROJ} in programs list")
        project(${PROJ})
        add_executable(${PROJ} ${PROJ}.c)
        target_link_libraries(${PROJ} LINK_PUBLIC pthread dl)
        install(TARGETS ${PROJ} DESTINATION ${BIN_DIR})
    else(${_index} GREATER -1)
        message(STATUS "${PROJ} is NOT in the programs list!!! ******")
    endif(${_index} GREATER -1)
endforeach()
```